# AngularJS: Objects and data available from parent component?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on a large web application written using AngularJS. Unfortunately, I only know Angular well from version 2, so I have a question about data passing. I need to develop a component that makes use of an **existing component** (whose code is really long and complex) and dynamically shows results based on the existing component. So I have a template of my component like this (`my-component.html`):

```
<div>
<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
</div>
<!-- Here I have to write the logic to dynamically display the information arrived with ng-trasclude -->
```

The template in which I use my component will then look like this:

```
<my-component>
    <component-made-by-other-developers 
              data1="$ctrl.CertainTypeOfObject"
              data2="anotherTypeOfObject"
     ></component-made-by-other-developers>
</my-component>
```

The question is: how do I use the data (in the example `data1` and `data2`) of the component developed by other developers within MY component (i.e. in the `my-component.js` and `my-component.html` files)? My problem is that the `ng-transclude` directive seems to give no access to the data of the other components (passed in input) if I want to use them in my own component. The question is: how can I use these data in my component (both template and controller)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ng-include` inside your component and pass the data by using `onload`

Your code should look something like this:

```
<div ng-include="otherDeveloperComponent.html" onload="passedData=$ctrl.CertainTypeOfObject; source='myComponent'" ng-if="true">
```